# create the anchor tag by using the morph relation in Laravel blade view

Tags: php, laravel, polymorphism

I have an application where an Invoice can belong to the client or supplier. Now I used the morph things in my current scenario. I want to create the proper anchor by using the morph relation But I didn't find the best way with Laravel

**Client.php**

```
class Client extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the client's invoices.
     */
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Invoice', 'contact');
    }
}
```

**Supplier.php**

```
class Supplier extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the supplier's invoices.
     */
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Invoice', 'contact');
    }
}
```

**Invoice.php**

```
class Invoice extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the owning contact model.
     */
    public function contact()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
```

Now at somewhere(invoice details page), where I want to add the anchor to the contact of the invoice(either supplier or client) But I need to know if there is any Laravel's way.

If the contact of the invoice belongs to App\Client then the href will be "/clients/contact_id" or if it belongs to App\Supplier then it should be "/supplier/contact_id"

**invoices/show.blade.php**

```
<a href=""><b>{{ $invoice->contact->name }}</b></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try given solution for you problem.

```
<?php

//You can see here for all table migration files

// For Client Table
Schema::create('client', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string("client_name");
    $table->timestamps();
    // You can add your more fields and you can change field name also
});


// For Supplier Table
Schema::create('supplier', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string("supplier_name");
    $table->timestamps();
    // You can add your more fields and you can change field name also
});

// For Invoice Table
Schema::create('invoices', function (Blueprint $table) {

    $table->increments('id');
    $table->morphs('invoice');
    $table->timestamps();
    // You can add your more fields and you can change field name also
});

//Note:
$table→morphs('invoice') would automatically create two columns using the text passed to it + “able”. So it will result in invoiceable_id and invoiceable_type.
?>
```

**Here are your model for morphTo replationship**

**Client Model:** Client.php

```
<?php
 
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Client extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the Client's invoices.
     */
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Invoices::class, 'invoiceable');
    }
}
?>
```

**Supplier Model:** Supplier.php

```
<?php
 
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Supplier extends Model
{
     /**
     * Get all of the Supplier's invoices.
     */
    public function invoices()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(Invoices::class, 'invoiceable');
    }
}
?>
```

**Invoices Model:** Invoices.php

```
<?php
 
namespace App;
 
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
 
class Invoices extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the owning invoiceable models.
     */
    public function invoiceable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}
?>
```

Now you can retrieve records using Client and Supplier using polymorphic relationship.

Retrieve records using client models.

```
$client = Client::find(1);  
dd($client->invoices);
```

Retrieve records using Supplier models.

```
$supplier = Supplier::find(1);   
dd($supplier->invoices);
```

You can also retrieve records

```
$client = Client::find(1);  
foreach ($client->invoices as $invoice) {
     <a href="{{ route('view-client', ['id' => $invoice->id]) }}">
         <b>{{ $invoice->client_name }}</b>
     </a>
}
```

Comment: I think you didn't see the actual issue. I know how to get data from invoice or inverse. I need to know that I want to make an anchor tag which ref to the contract detail page( client or supplier)